# are there any method to concatenate the name of an input tag with the integer variable which is increasing

Tags: html, jsp

I have included input tag in a while loop so I need to change the name of the input tags in the loop by concatenating the name by int variable which is increasing in the loop

I tried using $ mark but it doesn't work for me

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <% int a= 0;
        while(a<b){ 
            //out.println(ss);
            //out.println("Emp No"+a);
    %>
    Task Id: <input type="number" name="task_id${a}" value="<%=id%>">
    Emp Id: <input type="text" name="emp_id"><br>
    <% 
        a++;
    }%>
```

I need this name as name1,name2,name3.....

Answer (score 0):

Use similar [syntax](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31072&seqNum=7) as getting the id:

```
<input type="number" name="task_id<%=a%>" value="<%=id%>">
```

> In JSP, you can surround a Java expression in the tags <%= and %>. The expression's value is inserted into the Web page as text by the server.

If you want it to start with 1 just change `a` to start with 1 and check equal, see below:

```
int a= 1;
while(a<=b)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <% int a= 0;
        while(a<b){ 
            int c= a+1;
    %>
    Task Id: <input type="number" name="task_id<%=c%>" value="<%=id%>">
    Emp Id: <input type="text" name="emp_id"><br>
    <% 
        a++;
    }%>
```